# What advantage is there to using tf.lookup.StaticHashTable vs using tf.gather with tf.constant?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have about 500k rows of 512 dimensional int16 values, which will be retrieved and use for model inputs during training, with retrieval based on index.

I see that I can either store the data using `tf.constant`, and look up values using `tf.gather`, or I can use `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` to the store/retrieve the values.

Is there an advantage of doing one over the other?

I will be training my model over a TPU, if that makes a difference.